# How to "import" a UIView XIB into a UIViewController XIB?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I've seen a few answers here that seem to get at what I'm after, but I can't make any of them work.

`MyView` is a UIView subclass with a handful of images and text fields laid out and styled in `MyView.xib` and bound to IBOutlets in `MyView.(h|m)`. `File's Owner` is not set in the XIB, but MyView is the class of the top-level object. At runtime I dynamically load various MyViews into certain view controllers via `NSBundle's` `loadNibNamed`. Everything goes swimmingly.

But I have another view controller, `MyVC`, which at design time I would like to populate with a few instances of MyView. Following intuition, I laid out a UIView object in `MyVC.xib` with the same size as MyView, set its type to `MyView`, added an IBOutlet declaration in `MyVC.h`, and hooked up the connection.

When I run, `MyVC` shows no `MyView`. But debugging indicates that the connection is made, the view is indeed a `MyView`, and `MyView's` `awakeFromNib` does execute. And I'm sure that `MyVC's` `MyView` is on top of the hierarchy, because I set its background to a nice bright red. So where the devil is `MyView`?

Comment: The views are being `awakeFromNib`'d, but will have their `-initWithCoder` init method called, with the data from the view controller xib rather than MyView.xib. If that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make `MyView` have a single subview, which is a container for the rest of its descendant views.  This gives you a single point of contact between what's in `MyVC.xib` and what's in `MyView.xib`, and lets you connect outlets in both xibs.

In `MyVC.xib`, set the class of each placeholder view to `MyView`.

In `MyView.xib`, set the class of the top-level view to `UIView`.  Set the class of File's Owner to `MyView`.  If you have any outlets on `MyView` that were connected in `MyView.xib`, you will need to reconnect them to File's Owner since the top-level view no longer has those outlets.

In `-[MyView initWithCoder:]`, load `MyView.xib` and add its top-level view as your subview.  Untested example:

```
+ (UINib *)nib {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static UINib *nib;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass(self) bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:self]];
    });
    return nib;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        NSArray *contents = [[self.class nib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];
        UIView *containerView = contents[0];

        // Make sure the container view's size tracks my size.
        containerView.frame = self.bounds;
        containerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:)]) {
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
            containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
        }
        // If you're using autolayout in both xibs, you should probably create
        // constraints between self and containerView here.

        [self addSubview:containerView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This has the effect that you can connect `MyView`'s outlets to things in `MyVC.xib` and to things in `MyView.xib`, and you can connect the outlets of other objects in `MyVC.xib` and `MyView.xib` to the instance of `MyView`.  However, you can't connect outlets of other objects in `MyVC.xib` to other objects in `MyView.xib` or vice versa.

Comment: I'm not sure what I ever did with this, but your answer looks good.

Answer (score 0):

ORIGINAL: override initWithCoder, a bad idea as the comment below says

NEW SUGGESTION:

- create the MyVC view using the technique you have now (the MyView instances will essentially be empty views)

Then in the MyVC's viewDidLoad: method:

- create new MyView instances using your nib, one for each of the ones in MyView
- replace each of the empty (ie placeholder) MyViews with the ones you just created, making sure the frames are properly set (set any property/ivars, and use '- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2' to  replace the old view with the new one in the subview array)

Comment: This is not simple to get working.  When you load the nib, it will *also* use `initWithCoder:`.  You must take precautions to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @robmayoff guess this is what happens when you fool around with Mother Nature! Let me try again.